# Decide using com.auth0 or io.jsonwebtoken for JWT in Java

Tags: java, rsa, jwt, auth0, json-web-token

From today, I am learning the JWT process by myself. And I want to create a simple application, where I can create a token with RS256, and verify it. But I am not sure, which dependency should I use, and why:

1. com.auth0
2. io.jsonwebtoken

I found them in this link: https://jwt.io/

I also see that both of them can check everything. But how to decide which to use? I thing for now, the one with less code writing can be more interesting.

Thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've been using `nimbus-jose-jwt` for some time now and it is very easy to use.
If you want to choose between the two options you mentioned, I would go with `com.auth0`, mainly because it also looks very easy to use and much more mature and maintained than the other one.

HTH.